# UITableViewAccessoryType Randomly Not Showing

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

For each cell in the TableView I basically have a Boolean variable that stores if the data is being loaded for that cell. So tapping on a cell will cause the accessory type to change to a UIActivityIndicator. The TableView loads fine, but when I pop back to the TableView one or two of the cells randomly do not have the default DisclosureIndicator... it has nothing

The code I am using is inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
 NSLog([entry isLoading] ? @"Yes" : @"No");
if ([entry isLoading]) {
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView =
    [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [activityView startAnimating];
    [cell setAccessoryView:activityView];
}
else{
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
}
```

I have stepped through the code and the cells that do not show the DisclosureIndicator are still running the code that is setting it to a AccessoryDisclosureIndicator... I'm not sure what's going on since the cells missing the indicatory is triggering the else statement causing the `setAccessoryType`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
if ([entry isLoading]) {
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView =
    [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [activityView startAnimating];
    [cell setAccessoryView:activityView];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
}
else{
    [cell setAccessoryView:nil];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
}
```

As per [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html),

> **accessoryView**
>   If the value of this property is not nil, the UITableViewCell class
>   uses the given view for the accessory view in the table view’s normal
>   (default) state; it ignores the value of the accessoryType property.
>   The provided accessory view can be a framework-provided control or
>   label or a custom view. The accessory view appears in the right side
>   of the cell.

So you need to set `accessoryView` to nil show the `accessoryType` or else it will ignore it.